# "The development" or simply "development"?

Tags: articles

Here is a sentence similar to the one in the text I'm proofreading right now:
**Groundwork for (the) development and implementation of my cunning plan.**

The text is very formal and there're multiple instances of this "the" that to me appears to be doing nothing but the author is so insistent that I have lost my certainty :-) Googling gives no definite confirmation of whether I'm to take it out or leave it be so I decided to try and ask for advice. **Should the definite article be used with nouns denoting process in formal texts and circumstances?**

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the phrase 'development and implementation' is strictly correlated to your 'cunning plan', I would use 'the' before that.  However, without 'the' it is still semantically correct.

*[Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/article)* defines an articles as "*a kind of determiner, occurring in many languages including English, that lacks independent meaning but may serve to indicate the specificity of reference of the noun phrase with which it occurs*".

I am sure you remember that the **definite** article is 'the' and the **indefinite** articles are 'a' or 'an'; nevertheless, when speaking in very general terms, 'the' can be used instead of 'a' to make something less specific.*****

Another way to make a statement more general is to use no article at all.**†**

> * *The submission argues that the development "would destroy the
>   ambience that this small resort has enjoyed".* —Irish Times
>   (2002)
>
> † *He recalled Hyde's drawn, unshaven face watching him,
>   staring, like a photographic negative waiting for development,
>   reality.* —Thomas, Craig, The Last Raven (1990)

Conclusively, it does not exist a grammatical rule to correlate the 'the' use to nouns denoting process in formal texts and circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it sounds a little awkward without the *the*:

> *Groundwork for development and implementation of my cunning plan.*

If you don't like the article, I'd recommend this format:

> *Groundwork for developing and implementing my cunning plan.*